# Django, check django.db.Model subclass implementation

Tags: python, django, metaclass

I am creating a subclass of Django's Model class, and require the user to implement some attributes and methods. I did it by inheriting from ABC

```py
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase


class AbstractFooMeta(ModelBase, ABCMeta):
    """To avoid metaclass conflicts"""


class AbstractFoo(ABC, models.Model, metaclass=AbstractUploadMeta):
    my_num: int
    magic_string: str
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @abstractmethod
    def do_thing(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def do_class_thing(cls):
        pass


class AbstractMagicFoo(AbstractFoo):
    magic_str = "answer is 42"


class Foo(AbstractMagicFoo):
    my_num = 7

    def do_thing(self) -> str:
        print('did the thing')

    @classmethod
    def do_class_thing(cls) -> str:
        print('did the class thing')
```

I can create the migration, but when I try to run the migration I get:

```
  File "/home/michael/.venv/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 362, in reload_model
    self._reload(related_models)
  File "/home/michael/.venv/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 395, in _reload
    self.apps.render_multiple(states_to_be_rendered)
  File "/home/michael/.venv/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 597, in render_multiple
    model.render(self)
  File "/home/michael/.venv/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 872, in render
    return type(self.name, bases, body)
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I am guessing Django is not using the meta class I defined.
I tried setting the metaclass on all child classes but did not help.

How can I attach some logic to `AbstractFoo` that when a concrete class (i.e. not `AbstractMagicFoo`, but only with `Foo`), it performs checks that the following attributes and methods have been implemented:

- `my_num`
- `magic_str`
- `do_thing`
- and `do_class_thing`?

And if any of the checks fail, it raises an error. I am trying to get the error to occur when the class is defined, i.e. before it is instantiated, because it might not be instanatiated at a long time.

I would make my own metaclass to perform the checks, but then I am back to square one with the metaclass error during migration.

The None ideal solution I came currently doing: I created instance methods that raise `NotImplementedError`s if they are not subclassed. Not ideal, because an error is only found during run time, not class creation.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of solved it by adding the check to a custom meta class, which surprisingly  worked with Django migrations:

```py
class AbstractFooMeta(ModelBase, ABCMeta):
    """Not using ABC with django.db.Model because it errors out when running a migration"""

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        Class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs)
        if not Class.Meta.abstract:
            # Only check concrete models, e.g. not for Example AbstractS3Upload
            if not hasattr(Class, 'my_num'):
                raise NotImplementedError('Please add a my_num attribute')
        return Class
```